# выдает ошибку в 49 строке

Tags: python, pygame

```
from pygame import *


mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("space.ogg")
mixer.music.play()


window = display.set_mode((1000,700)) #oкнo
display.set_caption('Шутер')

clock = time.Clock()

bg = transform.scale(image.load('galaxy.jpg'),(1000,700)) #фон




class Ship(sprite.Sprite):
   def init(self, window):
       super(Ship, self).init()

       self.window = window

       self.w = 70
       self.h = 70

       self.win_rect = window.get_rect()

       self.y = 0
       self.x = self.win_rect.centerx

       self.ship = transform.scale(image.load('rocket.png'),(self.w,self.h))

       self.rect = self.ship.get_rect()

   def blit(self):
       self.window.blit(self.ship, self.rect)

   def upravlenie(self):
       k_s = key.get_pressed()
       if k_s[K_LEFT] and self.x > 0:
           self.x -= 10
           print(self.h)
           print(self.w)
       elif k_s[K_RIGHT] and self.x < 925:
           self.x += 10

ship = Ship(window)

class Bullet(sprite.Sprite):
   def init(self, window, ship):
       super(Bullet,self).init()

       self.window = window
       self.rect = Rect(0, 0, 2, 12)
       self.speed = 1
       self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
       self.rect_top = ship.rect.top 
       self.y = self.rect.y

   def update(self):
       self.y -= self.speed
self.rect.y = self.y




class Enemy(sprite.Sprite):
   def init(self, window, x = 100, y = 0):
       super(Enemy, self).init()

       self.window = window


       self.enemy = image.load('ufo.png')

       self.rect = self.enemy.get_rect()

       self.rect.x = self.rect.width
       self.rect.y = self.rect.height

       self.x = float(self.rect.x)
       self.y = float(self.rect.y)

   def blit(self):
       self.window.blit(self.enemy, self.rect)

   def update(self):
       self.y -= 0.1
       self.rect.y = self.y

enemies = sprite.Group()

def enemy_group(window, enemies):
   enemy = Enemy(window)

   for i in range(5):
       enemy = Enemy(window)
       enemies.add(enemy)
       enemy.rect.x += 100
   enemy.rect.x = 400
bullet = Bullet(window, ship)

enemy_group(window, enemies)


run = True

while run != False:
   window.blit(bg,(0,0))

   ship.blit()
   ship.upravlenie()







   k_s = key.get_pressed()

   if k_s[K_SPACE]:
       bullet.avto()

   for e in event.get():
       if e.type == QUIT:
           run = False
   display.update()
   clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Какую ошибку и в какой именно строке (не номер)?

Comment: File "c:/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Algoritmika/vscode/data/extensions/algoritmika.algopython-20230221.174607.0/data/student/1276433/184431/shooter_game.py", line 49, in <module>
    ship = Ship(window)
  File "C:\Users\Перадзе\AppData\Local\Programs\Algoritmika\algovenv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Algoritmika\algovenv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not pygame.Surface

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает на строке ship = Ship(window), в методе init() класса Ship.

В методе init() необходимо изменить первую строку, чтобы использовать правильное имя метода **init**, а также добавить параметр self в первую строку методов upravlenie и blit.

После этого необходимо добавить создание группы спрайтов и добавление корабля в эту группу. Ниже приведен исправленный код для класса Ship

```
class Ship(sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self, window, group):
       super(Ship, self).__init__(group)

       self.window = window

       self.w = 70
       self.h = 70

       self.win_rect = window.get_rect()

       self.y = 0
       self.x = self.win_rect.centerx

       self.ship = transform.scale(image.load('rocket.png'),(self.w,self.h))

       self.rect = self.ship.get_rect()

   def blit(self):
       self.window.blit(self.ship, self.rect)

   def upravlenie(self):
       k_s = key.get_pressed()
       if k_s[K_LEFT] and self.x > 0:
           self.x -= 10
           print(self.h)
           print(self.w)
       elif k_s[K_RIGHT] and self.x < 925:
           self.x += 10

       self.rect.x = self.x
       self.rect.y = self.y

ship_group = sprite.Group()
ship = Ship(window, ship_group)
```

Также необходимо добавить обновление и отрисовку группы спрайтов кораблей в цикле игры. Это можно сделать следующим образом

```
while run != False:
   window.blit(bg,(0,0))

   ship_group.update()
   ship_group.draw(window)

   ship.upravlenie()
   ship.blit()

   k_s = key.get_pressed()

   if k_s[K_SPACE]:
       bullet.avto()

   for e in event.get():
       if e.type == QUIT:
           run = False
   display.update()
   clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)